# OpenGL ES translation and rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es

Wasnt sure whether to post this here or in GameDev, but since it's not really game development i decided to ask here.

I'm trying OpenGL ES 2 on Android and right now i have a simple setup. I load an object from a .obj file, display it on the screen, then i can rotate the camera around the object using touch controlls. My viewMatrix is setup like this:

```
double[] dist = {DISTANCE * Math.sin(yawAngle) * Math.abs(Math.cos(pitchRollAngle)),
        DISTANCE * Math.sin(pitchRollAngle),
        DISTANCE * Math.cos(yawAngle) * Math.abs(Math.cos(pitchRollAngle))};

Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, (float) dist[0], (float) dist[1], (float) dist[2], 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

And my projection matrix is just this:

```
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 100);
```

I set the yaw / pitchRoll angle from touch events. Now this works ok, when the object is in the center of the screen, i can rotate around like i should. But if i try to move the object, say, 1 unit on the X axis like this:

```
float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

And then multiply all of them like this:

```
float[] MVPMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0);
```

The object spins around on its place, but i want it to rotate around the `(0, 0, 0)` point. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most general questions about matrix multiplication. In your case you need to first rotate the object and then translate it. So if you translate first to X and then rotate, the object will appear at position X but rotated around its own axis. If you rotate first and then translate by X the object will not appear at X but at the point gotten by rotating the X itself. This is an expected result and is how it works.

So to understand what happens: The matrix actually consists of 3 base vectors and a center. When identity the base vectors are `(1,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)`, `(0,0,1)`, `(0,0,0)`. Now when multiplying this matrix with some transformation the base vectors are actually transformed. That results is that the matrix is containing its own coordinate system in which the transformations seem "logical". This results that the rotation matrix will never change the center of the object.

I know this is all too complicated but it is actually very easy to imagine the effect: Take it as if matrix multiplication were actually commands to a character looking from a first person view. So when you say "go forward" (translate) you take a step forward, now "turn 90 degrees" and you turn 90 degrees and are still on the same location, now "go forward again" you take another step forward but this is actually not the same direction as it was on the beginning...

So what you do is you say "go forward by 1", now turn `ANGLE` degrees. This results in the object being kept in the same location and spinning around its own axis.
And what you should do is say "turn toward your goal" (rotate by `ANGLE`) now "go forward by 1" and maybe even "turn back by `-ANGLE`" so you face the same direction as you did in the beginning.

I hope this explanation will help you.

Comment: Nice explenation @Matic, seems logical now that I think about it! One thing is bugging me though, right now this is all good and well, since my camera only rotates around the object. But what would happen if i wanted to move the camera with the lookAt method? Then the view matrix would have both rotation and translation in it? How would i correctly multiply it then? Or should i create another matrix with the translation for the camera, and work forward from there, so that the view matrix only ever contains rotation? Or should i avoid the lookAt method and just do everything by hand?

Comment: I find it best to track 3 matrices, one containing projection (frustum or such), one for camera (look at) and a model matrix. Then simply multiply these 3 every frame. The projection is usually constant except if the viewport changes, the camera changes usually once per frame max and the model matrix changes for each model drawn. The lookAt is very helpful, you should use it if possible. As for your rotating object it is best for the object itself to hold the location and rotation and reconstruct the matrix by using these 2 values. So in your case you would be changing location only.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having a similar problem in Delphi 2010 when I had to use OpenGL there. The trick was to place the object back to <0, 0, 0>, applythe rotation and then place it back at its original  position before drawing a frame.
I can't recall how I did it, nor do I have access to that code anymore as it belonged to my previous employer, but that's what I remember.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work though, if i translate the object from `(0, 0, 0)` to `(1, 0, 0)` and rotate it by 180° around the Y axis I'd want it to be on `(-1, 0, 0)`. Or is this the expected result with your method?

Comment: Got it! Your answer helped, i just switched the model and view matrix, that is, the order in which they are multiplied (before the  model matrix was multiplied by the view matrix and now it's the other way around).

Comment: No problem, and glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in this line:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
```

I just switched the model and view matrix so that they are multiplied the other way around, and it works! Like this:

```
 Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
```

Thanks to @Zubaja for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: This might work for your case because you have only 2 operations but generally this is a very bad idea.